# to change the tab index of mat-stepper using output

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

i am using mat-stepper for my view and in each mat-step there is a component with form.
when my form gets submitted i am passing an event using @output and receiving in parent component and incrementing the index of mat-stepper using stepper.next() but when I try to submit the form for first inside the component stepper is not able to change its tab. on the second try, it is working and the tab is changing.
HTML file

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper>
    <mat-step [completed]="false" label="Create Product Storage Location" [stepControl]="locationForm">
        <app-add-location (notify)='getLocationForm($event)'></app-add-location>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [completed]="false" label="Add Single or Multiple Products" [stepControl]="productForm">
        <app-add-product (notify)='getProductForm($event)'></app-add-product>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
        <p>your product is created successfully !!</p>
        <div>
        </div>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

typescript function

```
@ViewChild('stepper') myStepper: MatStepper;
getLocationForm(formGroup: FormGroup): void {
    this.locationForm = formGroup;
    if(this.locationForm.status == "VALID"){
      this.myStepper.next()
      console.log('selected index is after', this.myStepper.selectedIndex)
    }
  }
```

I want to change the tab index and show the next tab to be active.

Comment: This part is not very clear: "but it is now incrementing for the first time it is remaining same but for the second time it is working fine". Also, would you be able to create a stackblitz for that?

Comment: i have edited question @GCSDC

Comment: Is `this.myStepper.next()` being triggered the first time you submit the form?

Comment: @GCSDC yess function is invoked but for first time even after .next() its selected index is 0.

Comment: Got it! If you're able to create a stackblitz, let me know and I will try to help you solving that.

Comment: @GCSDC sorry to say i can not share much code of now but i did found a solution just by replacing ` this.myStepper.next()`  to  `  this.myStepper['_selectedIndex'] += 1; ` i dont know why when i was trying to to ` this.myStepper.selectedIndex += 1;` it was not working on first time from submission.